# Where does the identity matrix come from in the formula for ridge regression coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, regression, regularization

The formula for the ridge regression coefficients is

$$ \beta = {X^{\top}Y}({X^{\top}X+\lambda I})^{-1}$$

I have tried to derive it as follows:

1. The loss is (I am omitting the sum before the square term):

$$ L = {(X^{\top}\beta-Y)^2+\lambda\beta^{\top}\beta} $$

2. Take the derivative and equating to zero:

$$ \frac{dL}{d\beta} = 2({X^{\top}\beta-Y)X}+2{\lambda \beta}$$

3. Equating the derivative to zero (we can get rid of the multipliers $2$) and expanding:

$$ X^{\top} X\beta- X^{\top} Y +\lambda \beta = 0 $$

4. Isolating beta:

$$ \beta ( X^{\top} X + \lambda) = X^{\top} Y$$

Here in the 4th step, I should somehow arrive at a formula that has $\mathbf I$ right after $\lambda$. Where I am making a mistake? I know it must be there but I don't understand why it should be there or based on what rule I should add it after $\lambda$. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $Y$ a vector?

Comment: Your notation needs drastic improvements. I mean *drastic*.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, it is a vector, but I thought that if we're talking about multiple regression from M predictor variables to N response variables, $Y$ can be an M by N matrix (and I hope I am correct).

Comment: Using uppercase for both matrices and vectors is confusing. Conventions exist for a reason. Proper notation can tell the reader in a tenth of a second what the types of each symbol are, even before the reader gets to the point where the symbols are formally introduced to the reader. Also, please clarify what the square of a vector is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule that says that $X^T X \beta + \lambda \beta = (X^T X + \lambda) \beta$. The expression on the right would not make sense, because we would be adding a matrix $X^T X$ to a scalar $\lambda$.

However, we can say that $X^T X + \lambda \beta = X^T X + \lambda I \beta = (X^T X + \lambda I) \beta$.

---

By the way, I would write the full calculation like this. Our goal is to minimize the function
$$
f(\beta) = \frac12 \| X \beta - Y \|^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2} \| \beta \|^2.
$$
Using the multivariable chain rule, we see that the derivative of $f$ is
$$
f'(\beta) = (X \beta - Y)^
T X + \lambda \beta^T.
$$
So the gradient of $f$ is
$$
\nabla f(\beta) = f'(\beta)^T = X^T(X \beta - Y) + \lambda \beta.
$$
Setting $\nabla f(\beta) = 0$, we obtain
$$
(X^T X + \lambda I) \beta = X^T Y.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here we are dealing with matrices and $\lambda$ is a scalar. So we can't add $X^TX$ with $\lambda$.

Also we can write $\beta = I\beta$. So, if we isolate $\beta$ we'll automatically have I inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly obtained $X^TX\beta+\lambda\beta=X^TY$, which has $i$th component $(X^TX)_{ij}\beta_j+\lambda\beta_i=(X^TY)_i$. Obviously, we mustn't conflate $\beta_i$ with $\beta_j$. But we can write the left-hand side in terms of $\beta_j$ only, using the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$: $$[(X^TX)_{ij}+\lambda\delta_{ij}]\beta_j=(X^TY)_i.$$The $\beta_j$ coefficient is $(X^TX+\lambda I)_{ij}$. If $X^TX+\lambda I$ is invertible, $$\beta=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY.$$